# In which sense does the ratio $x_3'/x_1'$ tell me the "Direction" of $x_2$?

Tags: real-analysis

If I have the derivative $x'=(x_1',x_2',x_3')$, in which way does the ratio $x_3'/x_1'$ tell me in which direction $x_2$ changes?

Comment: sorry, asked my question wrongly. edited it

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't, since a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is just a point. The ratio of 
two elements doesn't tell you anything about the direction of even those two coordinates, let alone a third, independent, one.

Edit: your edit doesn't really matter. Consider

$x_1 = t \\ x_2 = 0 \\ x_3 = t$

compared to $x_1 = t \\ x_2 = 5000t \\x_3 = t$

In both cases, $x_3'/x_1' = 1$, but $x_2'$ in the first case certainly doesn't equal $x_2'$ in the second case.

Comment: you are right, I made a mistake. i mean derivative. sorry, i edit my question!